# Multi instanced jPlayer with different skins

Tags: php, zend-framework, jplayer

I am currently having multiple jPlayers on my page with pink-flag as skin/theme.

But I want my 1st player to have blue-monday as skin/theme.
For changing this skin/theme new css file needs to be imported.
I have tried few options as @import to a particular div tag like:

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
 .jp-skin-blue {
 @import "skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css";
 }
</style>
```

But it is not working properly.

So how should I? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this using iframe, but it is having problem with pauseOthers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I added separate styles for both of those skins and updated the same with classes and files too.